# Collapsable sentence within paragraph in java swing jeditorpane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, collapsable

I want to create `collapsable` (or `foldable`) sentences. Importantly, they should be embedded into paragraphs and flow with the rest of the text. I'm working with Java / Swing, in a `JEditorpane` and an extension of the `DefaultStyledDocument`.
For instance:

> > [-] This is sentence
> >     one. [-] This is
> >     sentence two. [-] This is
> >     sentence three.

When sentence two is collapsed, it becomes:

> > [-] This is sentence
> >     one. [+] [-] This is
> >     sentence three.

The [webpage](http://java-sl.com/collapse_area.html) has an example of how to collapse a region of the document, but this region is not embedded into the paragraph. My problem is trying to decide which View to base this on.

- Create SentenceView as extension of **LabelView**: problem is that LabelView does not support sections with different style attributes.  Maybe I can add this, but most Views with multiple children are based on CompositeView.
- Create SentenceView as extension of **BoxView**: maybe, but I cannot figure out how to get this embedded into a ParagraphView in a way that it flows properly with the text.
- Extend **ParagraphView**: I could create some sort of super-aware ParagraphView that understands where sentences start and end and handles all the collapsing.  I could probably get this to work, but this is almost surely the wrong-way-to-do-it.

If anybody could give me a pointer (or gut feeling) what I could best base SentenceView on (or some other tip to help me a long) I would highly appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer my own question. After some code review of the standard Java Swing classes I decided that much of the functionality that I needed is implemented in `FlowView` and `ParagraphView`.  Notably, there is the `layoutRow` method of `FlowStrategy` that is responsible for finding breakpoints and delivering rows of text. In my `SentenceView` I have to do more or less exactly the same.  The only difference is that I don't want to layout rows myself.  Instead, my `SentenceView` needs to implement `breakView`, so that the paragraph that contains the sentence can cut up the sentence in pieces and lay them out. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way in which I can re-use the function `layoutRow` and I ended up copy/pasting a fair bit of that code.

During the implementation of my (collapsable) `SentenceView` I bumped into a number of Java 7 bugs.  For instance, see the [Java 7 line wrapping bug](http://java-sl.com/tip_java7_text_wrapping_bug_fix.html). Also, it seems to be ambiguous in Java whether the minimumSize is based on breakpoints at spaces (which are excellent break weights) or at characters (which are good break weights). `GlyphView` and `LabelView` give their minimumSize on the basis of excellent break weights, but `ParagraphView` mixes this with any breakpoints better than `BadBreakWeight` (see the code for `calculateMinorAxisRequirements`).  Which is rather confusing.

Anyway, let me highlight the most important parts of my implementation of `SentenceView`.  I'm leaving out the actual foldable part as it is a bit fiddly and not the part I was struggling with.  I'll focus on the `breakView` functionality.

```
public class SentenceView extends BoxView {
    boolean containsStart;
    boolean containsEnd;
    public SentenceView(Element elem) {
        super(elem, View.X_AXIS);
        containsStart = true;
        containsEnd = true;
    }
    ...
```

I also have a getter `isStart` for `containsStart` and `isEnd` for `containsEnd`.
The `breakView` method is mostly copied, as I said:

```
public View breakView(int axis, int p0, float pos, float len) {
    if (axis == View.Y_AXIS) return this;
    if (p0 == getStartOffset() && len >= getPreferredSpan(axis)) return this;
    float spanLeft = len;

    int p = p0;
    float x = pos;
    int end = getEndOffset();
    Row row = new Row(getElement());
    TabExpander te = (this instanceof TabExpander) ? (TabExpander)this : null;
    int breakWeight = BadBreakWeight;
    float breakX = 0f;
    float breakSpan = 0f;
    int breakIndex = -1;
    int n = 0;

    if (p0 == getStartOffset() && isStart()) row.setContainsStart(true);

    Vector<View> viewBuffer = new Vector<View>(10, 10);
    while (p < end && spanLeft >= 0) {
        View v = createView(p);
        if (v == null) break;

        int bw = v.getBreakWeight(axis, x, spanLeft);
        if (bw >= ForcedBreakWeight) {
            View w = v.breakView(axis, p, x, spanLeft);
            if (w != null) {
                viewBuffer.add(w);
            } else if (n == 0) {
                viewBuffer.add(v);
            }
            break;
        } else if (bw >= breakWeight && bw > BadBreakWeight) {
            breakWeight = bw;
            breakX = x;
            breakSpan = spanLeft;
            breakIndex = n;
        }

        float chunkSpan;
        if (v instanceof TabableView) {
                chunkSpan = ((TabableView)v).getTabbedSpan(x, te);
            } else {
                chunkSpan = v.getPreferredSpan(axis);
            }
        if (isEnd() && v.getEndOffset() == end) {
            if ((chunkSpan <= spanLeft) && (chunkSpan > spanLeft)) {
                spanLeft = chunkSpan - 1;
            }
        }
        if (chunkSpan > spanLeft && breakIndex >= 0) {

                if (breakIndex < n) {
                    v = viewBuffer.get(breakIndex);
                }
                for (int i = n - 1; i >= breakIndex; i--) {
                    viewBuffer.remove(i);
                }

                v = v.breakView(axis, v.getStartOffset(), breakX, breakSpan);
        }

        spanLeft -= chunkSpan;
        x += chunkSpan;
        viewBuffer.add(v);
        p = v.getEndOffset();
        n++;
    }
    // cloning:
    Vector<View> viewBuffer2 = new Vector<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < viewBuffer.size(); j++) {

        View v = viewBuffer.get(j);
        if (v instanceof MyLabelView) {
            v = (View) ((MyLabelView)v).createClone();
        }  else {
            throw new RuntimeException("SentenceView can only contain MyLabelView");
        }
        viewBuffer2.add(v);
    }
    View[] views = new View[viewBuffer2.size()];
        viewBuffer2.toArray(views);
        row.replace(0, row.getViewCount(), views);
        return row;
    }
```

There are a few things to note here. First, `breakView` will return itself or a `SentenceView.Row`. Secondly, I'm using a `MyLabelView` instead of `LabelView`, mostly because of the earlier mentioned line wrapping bug.  I'm still new to Java and Java Swing and I was struggling a bit with the `Cloneable` interface and `clone` is protected and final.  So, I just implemented `createClone` to call `clone`.  Not very elegant, but not my main worry either.  The cloning I needed because the subviews get reparented when they are added to a `Row`.  But, if at a later stage the original `SentenceView` gets displayed again (because breaking is no longer necessary), this leads to problems.  I think a better way may be to reparent all the subviews back to `this` but I could not figure out where to best do this.  I would welcome comments on this, though. Also, in order to actually implement foldability, the `SentenceView` will have to share its foldable status with the created `Rows`.  I did that by wrapping a boolean in an object and then sharing the object.

I'll give the following methods without code, as they are not too difficult or can be copied/amended from `ParagraphView`.

```
protected SizeRequirements calculateMajorAxisRequirements(int axis,
                                                 SizeRequirements r)
protected SizeRequirements calculateMinorAxisRequirements(int axis, SizeRequirements r)
public View createFragment(int p0, int p1)
protected View createView(int startOffset)

protected void layoutMinorAxis(int targetSpan, int axis, int[] offsets, int[] spans) {
    baselineLayout(targetSpan, axis, offsets, spans);
}
```

And then, finally, there is the `Row` inner class:

```
class Row extends SentenceView {
    Row(Element elem) {
        super(elem);
        containsStart = false;
        containsEnd = false;
    }
    public float getAlignment(int axis) {
        if (axis == View.X_AXIS) return 0;
        return super.getAlignment(axis);
    }

    public AttributeSet getAttributes() {
        View p = getParent();
        return (p != null) ? p.getAttributes() : null;
    }
    protected int getViewIndexAtPosition(int pos) {
        if(pos < getStartOffset() || pos >= getEndOffset())
            return -1;
        for(int counter = getViewCount() - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
            View v = getView(counter);
            if(pos >= v.getStartOffset() &&
               pos < v.getEndOffset()) {
                return counter;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    protected void loadChildren(ViewFactory f) {
    }
}
```

That works. It is a bit unfortunate that I ended up replicating quite a bit of existing code, but it isn't obvious to me how to implement `breakView` on the X axis in `paragraphView` or how to find another way to do this.  Also, in order to implement foldability, a bit more work needs to be done.  The `paint` method needs to be altered to draw [-] in front (if `containsStart` is true). The `minimumSize` and `preferredSize` need to take into account this extra bit of space (I'm using insets for that).  The `SentenceView` and the `Rows` it creates need to share the folded-status.  If the view is folded, the `minimumSize` and `preferredSize` will be equal to the size of the [+] marker.  There is some fiddling around with `viewToModel`, `modelToView`, `getNextEastWestVisualPositionFrom`.  This is all similar to [Folding (collapsible) area in the JEditorPane/JTextPane](http://java-sl.com/collapse_area.html). The only thing that I like a bit better in my code is the part in the mouse listener that checks whether the event took place inside a `SentenceView` as I'm avoiding the use of `viewToModel`.  So, let me give that as well:

```
MouseListener sentenceCollapse = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        JEditorPane src = (JEditorPane)e.getSource();
        View v = src.getUI().getRootView(src);
        Insets ins = src.getInsets();
        int x = ins.left;
        int y = ins.top;
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        p.translate(-x, -y);
        Rectangle alloc = new Rectangle(0,0,Short.MAX_VALUE,Short.MAX_VALUE);

        while (v != null && !(v instanceof SentenceView)) {
            View vChild = null;
            int n = v.getViewCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                Rectangle r = v.getChildAllocation(i, alloc).getBounds();

                if (r.contains(p)) {
                    vChild = v.getView(i); 
                    alloc = (Rectangle) r.clone();
                }
            }
            v = vChild;
        }
        if (v != null && v instanceof SentenceView) {
        <<< unfold or fold the Sentence View >>>
        src.repaint();
    }
};
```

Hope this is useful.